# Flutter installation failure

Tags: flutter

I have tried installing the flutter sdk but once I run the flutter doctor command on the terminal, the command prompt disappears.What could be the problem and how do I solve it?

I have tried deleting the sdk package and reinstalling it once again and even tried changing the environment variables. I expected to run the flutter doctor

Comment: Can you please elaborate more by adding the steps of installation, picture as proof or anything else that well help us to determine the issue